# Sum column values within the same group and save that dataframe separately

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
In [186]:

df = pd.read_csv(file, engine='python',sep='\t')
df

Out[186]:
length value   parent
        
100       5       X
 90      18       X
 77      17       Y
 15      15       Y
 89      11       Z
```

What do I do if I want to change this datframe into the following:

```
value   parent
        
  23    X
  32    Y
  11    Z
```

I am basically summing up the column values within the same group and saving that dataframe into a separate data frame. As you can see, I am not intested in the length column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Have you done a Pandas tutorial? Grouping values and selecting/dropping columns is Pandas 101. If you have and you're stuck, then what have you tried that didn't work? You can [edit] to clarify. If you haven't, you should do that first. This site isn't built to teach the basics. BTW, for tips, check out [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop the length column and do

```
df.groupby(['parent']).sum()
```

[documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)